# GDI+ Game Engine (What can I do to make my engine run faster?)

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

I'm currently working on a 2D Game Engine using GDI+. Everything is running quite smoothly, however I know there must be a few more things I can do to make my engine render graphics faster.

At the moment if I rendered an empty bitmap that's 800x600 pixels to the screen, I get about 130fps. But once I draw an image that's 800x600 pixels on the bitmap, I get about 70fps. That's not an issue at all, I'm actually proud of the results, I just know it can be better.

I was just wondering if anyone had any suggestions as to what might make the engine run even faster?

Here's the code to my window class:

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GameEngine.Graphics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;

namespace GameEngine.Core
{
    public class Game : Form
    {
        // Just a class that checks the fps and such
        private GameTime gameTime;
        private GraphicsEngine graphicsEngine;

        private bool isLoaded = false;
        private bool isRunning = false;

        public Game(int width, int height, string title)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            this.Text = title;

            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

            this.Paint += Game_Paint;
            this.FormClosing += Game_FormClosing;

            gameTime = new GameTime();
            graphicsEngine = new GraphicsEngine(this);

            Show();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Initialize();
            Load();

            isRunning = true;

            while (isRunning && isLoaded)
            {
                // Yes I know, this is frowned upon
                Application.DoEvents();

                gameTime.Update();

                // Only update if the form is focused and if the GameTime class says we're allowed
                if (this.Focused && gameTime.Cycled)
                {
                    BeginUpdate();
                    UpdateGame();
                    LateUpdate();
                    Render();
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }

            Exit();
        }

        public void Exit()
        {
            Unload();
            this.Close();

            // Using console application, so lets exit the console
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            gameTime.Initialize();
        }

        private new void Load()
        {
            isLoaded = true;
        }

        private void Unload()
        {

        }

        private void BeginUpdate()
        {

        }

        private void UpdateGame()
        {
            this.Title = "FPS: " + gameTime.FPS;
        }

        private void LateUpdate()
        {

        }

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("Test.jpg");

        private void Render()
        {
            // Draw the nice tree to the window
            graphicsEngine.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0);

            // Cause the window to redraw it's self
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private void Game_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Lets just make sure once again that we're allowed to draw
            if (gameTime.Cycled)
            {
                // Render the graphics to the screen
                graphicsEngine.Render(e.Graphics);
            }
        }

        private void Game_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            isLoaded = false;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return Text; }
            set { Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the graphics engine class:

```
    using System.Drawing;
using GameEngine.Core;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace GameEngine.Graphics
{
    public class GraphicsEngine
    {
        private Game game;

        private System.Drawing.Graphics backBuffer;
        private System.Drawing.Bitmap backBufferBitmap;

        public GraphicsEngine(Game game)
        {
            this.game = game;

            backBufferBitmap = new Bitmap(800, 600);
            backBuffer = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(backBufferBitmap);

            backBuffer.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            backBuffer.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            backBuffer.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            backBuffer.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
            backBuffer.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
            backBuffer.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        }

        public void Render(System.Drawing.Graphics g)
        {
            g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;

            g.DrawImage(backBufferBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, game.Width, game.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, game.Width, game.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            backBuffer.Clear(Color.Black);
        }

        public void DrawString(string text, int x, int y)
        {
            backBuffer.DrawString(text, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.White, x, y);
        }

        public void DrawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y)
        {
            backBuffer.DrawImage(bitmap, x, y);
        }

        public void DrawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            backBuffer.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it is focused on improving already working code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to operate a kind of Logical thread separated from your drawing thread. Maybe replace the thread sleeping in your logical by a  ([tick management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)).

As asked in comments below, the fact to separate UI & logic in different thread could help you to have a better flow in both tasks. The hard part is to keep UI and logic Synced, but you're less exposed to slow methods/function which would slow down UI.

Comment: indeed separating drawing and game logic is a sensible thing to do, it may need some syncing though (inconsistent game states may exist during the update). If you could elaborate your answer a bit OP might see the value.

Comment: I see how this would help, however since the code its self is already rendering slow, all this means is that it would render slow on a different thread.

Comment: Rendering and Game logic are two different things. Did you mixed logic and drawing function in your assets (in this case it will be a pain to apply suggested improvement) ?